# owlCarousel and trigger prev.owl.carousel and next.owl.carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have code

```
var owl_news = $("#owl-caro-news");
owl_news.owlCarousel({
    items : 5,
    navigation: true,
    navigationText : ["<div class='sprite left-arr'></div>","<div class='sprite right-arr'></div>"],
    pagination: false,
    itemsDesktop : [1000,4], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
    itemsDesktopSmall : [900,3], // betweem 900px and 601px
    itemsTablet: [600,2], //2 items between 600 and 0
});
var html = '<div class="owl-controls1"><div class="owl-buttons"><div class="owl-prev"><div class="sprite left-arr"></div></div><div class="owl-next"><div class="sprite right-arr"></div></div></div></div>';
$("#owl-caro-news").append(html);
```

and

```
$('#owl-caro-news .owl-controls1 .owl-next').on('click', function(e) {
$("#owl-caro-news .item a.active").parent().parent().next().find("a").click();
    owl_news.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
});
$('#owl-caro-news .owl-controls1 .owl-prev').on('click', function(e) {
$("#owl-caro-news .item a.active").parent().parent().prev().find("a").click();
    owl_news.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
});
```

but it does not work, clicking on the arrow does not scroll the active area

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: $('#owl-caro-news .owl-controls1 .owl-next').on('click', function(e) {



i use this that change next active element on slider and it work

Comment: $(document).on('click', '.owl-controls1 .owl-next', function(){
not help...